In My Web View screen Zoom in out not disable
I add an InAppWebView for show a webView and i want to disable zoom in zoom out
              InAppWebView(
                    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                      webView = controller;

                    webView?.setSettings(
                      settings:InAppWebViewSettings(builtInZoomControls:false)
                     );
                   },

                  initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(
                  clearCache: true,
                  cacheEnabled: false,
                  cacheMode: CacheMode.LOAD_NO_CACHE,
                  clearSessionCache: true,
                  supportZoom: false,
                  verticalScrollBarEnabled: false,
                  maximumZoomScale: 1,
                  minimumZoomScale: 1,
                  builtInZoomControls: false,
                  disableHorizontalScroll: true,
                  displayZoomControls: false
                ),
                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: WebUri('https://pub.dev/')),
              )


@DroidFlutter any solutions??

Try to replace webView?.setSettings with webView?.setSettings(settings:InAppWebViewSettings(builtInZoomControls:false,supportZoom: false,maximumZoomScale: 1,minimumZoomScale: 1,)

@DroidFlutter not working its working for first time in my app i have 5 screen for web view when open second screen it not work
